# Tree of inheritance of Git branches

Tags: git, sh, binary-search-tree

Is there any way to replicate an inheritance tree of Git branches in shell?

For example, I have local branches *b1*, *b2*, ... , *bN* as listed by `git branch`.

Example:

```
     ++ b7 <--+ b4
     |
b8 <--+ b5   +-+ b2
     |       |
     ++ b1 <---+ b3
             |
             +-+ b6
```

So, in the above case I would like to have a variables representing branch names (or their hashes, doesn't matter).

I know about binary search tree data structures in shell (at least one approach which is working nicely). The problem is how to get a proper left or right choice when submitting the branch into the BST-like structure?

I suppose I need to do something with `git branch --contains` and `git merge-base`, though I can't clearly see a picture of algorithm right now. The `git branch --contains` works quite slowly, perhaps because of nature of the tree, it would be also good to hear alternatives.

`libgit2` + python approach seems not the best choice to me because I need to rebase those branches and it looks like `libgit2` is quite low level for that.

Comment: This isn't entirely clear.  What behaviour/outcome/output do you want here?

Comment: It sounds like you want to write a fancy multi-rebase script. I attempted this once, and eventually gave up: there are too many difficult corner cases. Note that the information you're gathering is not something Git claims or enforces: branch names (all references, really) are just pointers to commits that can be moved arbitrarily at any time. Branch names have an "expected" movement while, e.g., tags are "expected" not to move at all, but one must keep in mind who, exactly, is doing this expecting...

Comment: How about `git branch --oneline --graph --decorate --all`? Does this give the output you are looking for?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, the output is BST-like structure where this inheritance tree is represented.

Comment: @torek, you roughly got the idea, though in my particular case the inheritance like in example is warranted.

Comment: Ok.  I'm not sure a shell language is what you want here - they're really not designed for manipulating data structures.  Something like Python (as you suggested) sounds like a much better bet.

Comment: @CodeApprentice, perhaps, I will check that later, but I’m not looking for any output at the end. I need that to be in a data structure in shell program.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, I pointed to the actual impediment I have right now is the function which tells me where to place the branch in the tree. Though with python is another problem, libgit2 is too low level, so I see no advantages there. C on the other hand might be the real solution (patching actual Git source).

Comment: actually, I'm not sure that it is correct to represent branches as **binary** tree. Consider a history where you have N branches which have only the very first commit in common, and the rest is independent. How you think the tree should look like? Probably you should descibe the bigger problem which you are trying to solve

Comment: Shells don't *have* data structures. They have strings. If you are using a shell like `bash`, you get arrays, which are *kind* of like data structures, but they can't be nested, which is going to be critical for storing a tree. `ksh` allows nested arrays, but I don't know what it's really like to work with them.

Comment: @max630, OK, perhaps something like radix tree (in Linux kernel), where each slot may contain up to 64 siblings. So, it looks like I need to add a node with let's say following properties `name_of_parent_branch`, `name_of_the_branch_in_question` and re-balance tree.

Comment: @chepner, thanks for teaching me, though I know it. Shell has enough means to emulate some more complex data structures.

Answer (score 1):

Does this command's output look like what you want:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --simplify-by-decoration --all
```

Comment: Nope, it's quite far from what I wanted. I need to get a picture closed to the example above. In this case I got a tons of not-related stuff in unparseable form.