# Modifying git commits, and applying to all subsequent branches in one command

Tags: git, git-branch, rebase, git-rebase, branching-and-merging

In a git repo, I have many serial commits up until one commit, named Z.

I have 3 branches (A, B & C) directly off of Z.

I want to modify some commits (X & Y) before Z, and I want those changes applied all subsequent branches (e.g. the 3 branches off of Z, namely A, B & C).

From what I've seen, I can interactively rebase for only one of A, B, or C at a time, so I'd have to rebase A, generating Z', then rebase B onto Z', then rebase C onto Z'.

That seems ridiculous.

Is there any way I can modify X & Y, then have those changes flow through all downstream branches in just one command?

I've done it manually with IntelliJ for these 3 branches, but it will be annoying to have to do this every time I update an old commit.  I know that normally you shouldn't update old commits, but I'm working on a project by myself, and there are reasons why old commits should be updated.  Almost no changes that I might make in commits before Z will cause any conflicts with commits in B or C that are after Z, so it would be nice to just have the changes applied to A, B & C if there are no conflicts, either with the option to resolve conflicts, or just to skip the branches in which there are conflicts, forcing me to fix them up in a separate command.

Comment: No, it's not ridiculous. Each branch may have quite different conflicts with a new base. That's why you have to do this manually (or rather sequentially, or in parallel in independent worktrees, but with possible non-automatic conflict resolution).

Comment: I asked for some help to automate one script I have
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478015/tree-of-inheritance-of-git-branches. Though no luck, I have the tree of inheritance to be hardcoded in the script. If you wonder, script is here: https://github.com/andy-shev/home-bin-tools/blob/master/gu4all.sh

Comment: Yeah, but I should be able to run one command, and then deal with each branch in succession.  I don't want to have to type multiple arcane git commands to deal with this.  The CLI for git is terrible, and I don't want to get one of may commands wrong.

Comment: This kind of automation isn't built directly into git. You could build it yourself with a bash script.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for the info, @0andriy

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for the info, @Code-Apprentice